# Retrofit Response Error with Content type text/html

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am having issue with an API service ,

```
https://api.litzscore.com/rest/v2/recent_matches/
```

I think the issue is with their Response Header Content type,When i contacted them they said like this

> Its should be possible to load the response as string and parse it as JSON. Your library not understanding our content type. 
>   [image: LogCat]

The Content type in response is

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, application/json
```

Is there is way that i can overcome this..?
I am using Retrofit + OKHttp

Comment: i am not 100% sure, but the error talks about UTF-8, unsupportedEncoding... which is strange too...as every java implementation should have UTF8, anyways, try this line,just add it inside `onCreate()` without any action or API calls, `java.nio.charset.Charset utf8 = java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8");` did you get error?

Comment: @Yazan that's not working

Comment: i am not sure but i think it's java, not the API, can you try another device or emulator?

Comment: Can u post ur code snippet....

Comment: @GET("/recent_matches/")
    public void getRecentMatches(Callback<MatchList> callback);
 new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setClient(mOkClient)
                .setEndpoint(WEB_API_ENDPOINT)
                .setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

Answer (score 1):

@Headers({"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"})